# How create complex number matrix in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create complex number matrix class using Python.
My first method work with one class and complex(self.real,self.imag) :
Operator overloading +-* is ok.

```
class zcomplex:
def __init__(self,rows,real,imag):
    self.rows=rows
    self.real=real
    self.imag=imag
    self.tab=[[complex(self.real,self.imag)]*self.rows for i in range(rows)]
    
def __add__(self,other):
    tmp=zcomplex(self.rows,0,0)
    for i in range(self.rows):
        for j in range(self.rows):
            tmp.tab[i][j]= self.tab[i][j] + other.tab[i][j]
    return tmp

def __sub__(self,other):
    tmp=zcomplex(self.rows,0,0)
    for i in range(self.rows):
        for j in range(self.rows):
            tmp.tab[i][j]= self.tab[i][j] - other.tab[i][j]
    return tmp

def __mul__(self,other):
    tmp=zcomplex(self.rows,0,0)
    for i in range(self.rows):
        for j in range(self.rows):
            for k in range(self.rows):
                tmp.tab[i][j]+= self.tab[i][j] * other.tab[i][j]
    return tmp

def prm(self):
    for i in range(self.rows):
        print(self.tab[i])
    print('')


a=zcomplex(3,4,6)
a.prm()

b=zcomplex(3,1,2)
b.prm()

print('c+a+b')
c=a+b
c.prm()

print('d=a-b')
d=a-b
d.prm()

print('e=a*b')
e=a*b
e.prm()
```

But i want by means of inheritance similar in C++.

```
class zcomplex:
def __init__(self,real=1,imag=0):
    self.real=real
    self.imag=imag
def display(self):
    print((self.real,self.imag))

class zmatrix(zcomplex):
    def __init__(self, real=0,imag=0,rows=3):
        self.rows=rows
        zcomplex.__init__(self,real,imag)
        self.tab=[[(real,imag)]*self.rows for i in range(self.rows)]
    def display(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            print(self.tab[i])

a=zmatrix()
a.display()

b=zcomplex()
b.display()
```

but does not work.
In c++ i can use tab[i][j].real
How i can fix this problem without numpy?

Thank you for your attention and help!

For tab[i][j].real I meant how overload operator +,- and *
for second case.

In c++ i can:

```
zmatrix zmatrix :: operator-(const zmatrix & zarray)
```

{
zmatrix temp(rows,columns);

```
for(int i =0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        temp.ptab[i][j].real=ptab[i][j].real - zarray.ptab[i][j].real;
        temp.ptab[i][j].imag=ptab[i][j].imag - zarray.ptab[i][j].imag;
    }
}
return temp;
```

}

```
/*zmatrix zmatrix :: operator*(const zmatrix& TABLICA)
```

{
zmatrix temp(rows,columns);

```
for(int i =0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        temp.ptab[i][j].real=temp.ptab[i][j].imag=0;
        for(int k=0; k < rows; ++k)
        {
            temp.ptab[i][j].real = temp.ptab[i][j].real + (TABLICA.ptab[i][k].real * ptab[k][j].real) - (TABLICA.ptab[i][k].imag * ptab[k][j].imag); //-28+16i
            temp.ptab[i][j].imag = temp.ptab[i][j].imag + (TABLICA.ptab[i][k].real * ptab[k][j].imag) + (TABLICA.ptab[i][k].imag * ptab[k][j].real);
        }
    }
}
return temp;
```

} */

Comment: this is the wrong path forward.  Numpy has native complex arrays, and they're high performance.  Someone has literally spent years building what you are trying to, so just use that

Answer (score 0):

If you want `tab[i][j].real` to be a valid expression, then you have to create `tab` as a matrix of `zcomplex` objects.  You're not doing that.  But you could.  Here's your code with the simple change that will do that:

```
class zcomplex:
    def __init__(self,real=1,imag=0):
        self.real=real
        self.imag=imag
    def display(self):
        print((self.real,self.imag))

class zmatrix(zcomplex):
    def __init__(self, real=0,imag=0,rows=3):
        self.rows=rows
        zcomplex.__init__(self,real,imag)
        self.tab=[[zcomplex(real,imag)]*self.rows for i in range(self.rows)]
    def display(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            print(self.tab[i])

a=zmatrix()

b=zcomplex()

# this now works...prints `0`
i = 2
j = 1
print(a.tab[i][j].real)
```

UPDATE:

I don't understand what you expect to gain by having `zmatrix` inherit from `zcomplex`.  A matrix, after all, isn't itself ever a complex number.  A `zmatrix` is a container of `zcomplex` objects.

What you're doing to build each row of your matrix won't work.  `[(real,imag)]*self.rows` will create a list with 3 references to the same tuple, which isn't what you want, right?.  Likewise, `[zcomplex(real,imag)]*self.rows` will create a list with 3 references to the same `zcomplex` object.  So you need to build each row a bit differently.

Here's a version of your code with changes for the two things I mention above.  I also added `__repr__` methods to make it possible to trivially print the contents of instances of each of your classes.  Finally, I added some code to demo that this code does work:

```
class zcomplex:
    def __init__(self,real=1,imag=0):
        self.real=real
        self.imag=imag
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<r:{self.real} i:{self.imag}>'
    def display(self):
        print(self)

class zmatrix:
    def __init__(self, real=0 ,imag=0, rows=3):
        self.rows=rows
        self.tab=[[zcomplex(real,imag) for _ in range(rows)] for _ in range(self.rows)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(' '.join(str(c) for c in self.tab[i]) for i in range(self.rows))
    def display(self):
        print(self)

a=zmatrix()
print(a)

a.tab[0][0].real = 123
a.tab[1][1].real = 456
a.tab[2][2].real = 789

a.tab[0][2].imag = 999
a.tab[1][1].imag = 888
a.tab[2][0].imag = 777

print('\n', a, sep='')
```

Result:

```
<r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:0>
<r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:0>
<r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:0>

<r:123 i:0> <r:0 i:0> <r:0 i:999>
<r:0 i:0> <r:456 i:888> <r:0 i:0>
<r:0 i:777> <r:0 i:0> <r:789 i:0>
```